# The Fourier transform and dirac delta

Tags: fourier-transform

The integral of an exponential can be written as a delta function

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ikx}  dk = 2\pi\delta(x)$$

In proving this I start with the definition of a fourier transform.

$$(1)\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space f(x) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(k) e^{ikx}  dk$$

$$(2)\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space F(k) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-ikx} dx$$

By substituting (2) into (1),

$$(1)\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space f(x) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x')e^{-ikx'} dx'\space e^{ikx} dk$$

From there, in most proofs I've read over, they bring the exponential term $e^{-ikx'}$ out of the integrand of $dx'$ and join the two exponentials to make $e^{ik(x-x')}$.

How can the $e^{-ikx'}$ term be brought outside of the integrand of $dx'$ without changing the value of the integral?

Comment: Kindly reserve $\delta(\cdot)$ for the delta function and use $dx$ in the integral.

Comment: You should try proving that $\int_{-a}^a e^{ik x}dk = \frac{2\sin(a x)}{x}=a \, h(ax), h(x) = \frac{2\sin( x)}{x}$ converges to $2\pi\delta(x)$, as $a \to \infty$  and **in the sense of distributions**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to bring the $e^{-ikx'}$ outside of any integration; rather, you are bringing the $e^{ikx}$ inside the $dx'$ integration. Doing so, you'll get:
$$
\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x') e^{ik(x-x')}\, \, dx' dk
\end{align*}
$$
Now, switch the order of integration, giving
$$
\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x') e^{ik(x-x')}\, \, dk dx'
\end{align*}
$$
and then bring out $f(x')$ from the $dk$ integral:
$$
\begin{align*}
  f(x) &=  \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x') \left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ik(x-x')}\,  dk \right) dx'
\end{align*}
$$
and what you want is now immediate.